# Copying /usr/lib64/libstdc.6.0.32 over /usr/local/lib64/libstdc.6.0.31 to satisfy configure -> cmake?

Tags: libstdc++

The build:

```bash
$ cd /usr/local/src/HandBrake/HandBrake-1.6.1
$./configure

$ version probe: cmake 3.16.3...(fail) 0.0.0
ERROR: minimum required cmake version is 3.16.3 and /usr/bin/cmake is 0.0.0

$ cmake
cmake: /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.32' not found (required by   cmake)
```

The fix:

The distribution comes with GCC 13.1.1 which uses `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.32`.

I installed GCC 13.1.0 in `/usr/local/bin` which uses `/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.31`.

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib64
$ cp /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.32 .
$ ln -s libstdc++.so.6.0.32 libstdc++.so.6
$ ln -s libstdc++.so.6.0.32 libstdc++.so
```

Background:

Fedora 38 current level is GCC 13.1.1.
I would build GCC 13.1.1 if I could find the source code.

Questions:

Is copying a library like this regarded as wrong?

What dictates which version of GCC to use? (gcc 9, 10, 11, 12, 13).

Comment: use the cmake from the official Fedora 38 sources. not whatever random rpm you've installed.

Comment: It's not about cmake. It's libstdc++ in the compiler......